# Show string keys instead of values

Tags: android, localization, android-resources

Is it possible to show the keys of my strings in strings.xml instead of the value, would be cool to check which key is it directly in the UI.

for example

```
<string name="jobs_key">Jobs</string>
```

i would like to show in the UI `jobs_key` instead of `Jobs`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `Resources.getResourcesName(int)`,

> Return the full name for a given resource identifier

[here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getResourceName%28int%29) you can find the documentation. You can also use reflection:

```
  private ArrayList<String> getKeysName(Context context, String className) {
        Class c;
        ArrayList<String> fieldsName = new  ArrayList<String>();
        try {
            c = Class.forName(context.getPackageName() + ".R$" + className);
            Field[] fields = c.getDeclaredFields();
            for (Field f : fields) {
                Log.e("LOG_TAG", " " + f.getName());
                fieldsName.add(f.getName());
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return fieldsName;
    }
```

and call it like  `getKeysName(context, "string");`, to get, for instance all the keys declared inside string.xml.

Comment: is there also a global way ? most of my strings are in xml.files

Comment: i would like to display the key in the UI everywhere

Comment: and why can not you use the method I suggested you? For UI you need a Context and trough context you can access resources

Comment: sorry but i don't see an easy way to do this with this method for my whole project